# Euler Totient $\phi(n) = n-7$, find all integers

Tags: number-theory

An old exam paper without solutions has this question:

> Find all positive integers n such that $\phi(n) = n-7$.
>
> [Hint: If n > 1 is not prime then there is a prime $p$ dividing $n$ such that $p < \sqrt x$ ]

The hint alludes to the previous part of the question:

> If $p$ is a prime dividing the integer $n$, then prove that $\frac{\phi(n)}{n} \le 1 - \frac{1}{p}$.

Now I can do the previous part fine, and the hint leads me to conclude that $ n \le 49$ since $n$ can't be prime, and so $n - 7 = \phi(n) \le n - \frac{n}{p} \le n - \frac{n}{\sqrt n} = n - \sqrt n $   so   $ \sqrt n \le 7 $.

But where do I go from here? I saw that $49$ worked since there are only $7$ numbers less than $49$ divisible by $7$, but another $n$ satisfying $ \phi(n) = n - 7$ is $15$ of all numbers. which I know how to check, with $\phi(15) = (5-1)(3-1) = 8 = 15 - 7$. The question is only worth a few marks and so I assume I'm missing some easy trick.

Comment: it seems you can do that almost by brute force: the only possible divisors are $2,5,7$, and using the previous question you find that if 2 is a divisor then $n \leq 14$, if 3 is a divisor then $n \leq 21$ and if $5$ is a divisor then $n \leq 35$. so you "just" need to check $4,6,8,10,12,14,7,21,15,25,49$

Comment: It's not clear how you deduced that all the prime divisors must be $\leq 7$, @Glougloubarbaki (I think it's true, but the OP didn't show it.)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, $n-7\le n-\frac np$ (and so $n\le 7p$) for *any* prime $p$ dividing $n$. Thus we know

- $n$ cannot be prime because then $\phi(n)=n-1$.
- $n\ge 8$ because $\phi(n)\ge1$.
- If $n$ is divisible by $2$, then $n\le 14$. We check $\phi(10)=4\ne 3$, $\phi(12)=4\ne 5$, $\phi(14)=6\ne 7$
- If $n$ is divisible by $3$, then $n\le 21$. As we know $2\nmid n\ne 3$, we check $\phi(9)=6\ne 2$, $\color{red}{\phi(15)=8}$, $\phi(21)=12\ne 14$.
- If $n$ is divisible by $5$, then $n\le 35$. As we know $2\nmid n$, $3\nmid n$, and $n\ne 5$, we check $\phi(25)=20\ne 18$, $\phi(35)=24\ne 28$
- So *all* prime divisors are $\ge 7$, thus allowing only $49, 77, \ldots$
  But as you showed, $n\le 49$. So we check $\color{red}{\phi(49)=42}$.

Comment: Alternative argument for even $n$: $n$ can't be divisible by $4$ because $\phi(n)$ and $n$ have to have different parities. Likewise, if $n$ is even and has an odd prime factor, then $\phi(n)$ and $n$ are both even. So if $n$ is even, then $n=2$.